# How do I create an array that repeats every number twice?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sequence

I want to create an array with the following structure when printed:

1: (10,20),

2: (20,30),

3: (30,40),

4: (40,50),

and so on...

Really new to python so anything helps! Using python 3.

Comment: Is it array of tuples?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: Python arrrays - are very seldomly used - or do you mean numpy? or list? you print tuples ... this is quite unclear -what did you try ? [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do by python [range](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) function range(start, end, stepsize)

```
final_lst = []
for i in range(10, 200, 10):
    final_lst.append([i, i+10])
print(final_lst)
```

output

```
[[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 40], [40, 50], [50, 60], [60, 70], [70, 80], [80, 90], [90, 100], [100, 110], [110, 120], [120, 130], [130, 140], [140, 150], [150, 160], [160, 170], [170, 180], [180, 190], [190, 200]]
```

::edit::

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print('%s: (%s,%s),'%(i, i*10, (i+1)*10))
```

output

```
1: (10,20),
2: (20,30),
3: (30,40),
4: (40,50),
5: (50,60),
6: (60,70),
7: (70,80),
8: (80,90),
9: (90,100),
```

Answer (score 0):

take two variables cnt1 and cnt2

```
import numpy as np    
myList = []
cnt1=1
cnt2=2
for i in range(n):  #n is desired length
    myList.append([10*cnt1,10*cnt2])
    cnt1+=1
    cnt2+=1
myArray = np.array(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that uses `range` to get a range of values and a list comprehension (basically an inline for-loop) to generate a list of tuples. Something like this:

```py
def get_repeated_list(max_n):
    values = range(10, max_n, 10)
    return [(i, i+10) for i in values]
```

Example usage:

```py
>>> get_repeated_list(50)
[(10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want to do is is transform a list into another list of previous/next elements.

```py
listA = [ 10 * i for i in range( N ) ]

listB = [ (listA[ i ], listA[ i + 1 ]) for i in range( len( listA ) - 1 ) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let l be your list. It doesn't matter what is in it. Use zip to make a new list, with wanted feature. `zip`, matches elements of two list together. if you `zip` a list with itself, you'll have a new list that each element in first list is repeated twice in it.

`l = [1, 2, 5, 11, 12]
for element in zip(l, l):
     print(element)`

output:

`(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(5, 5)
(11, 11)
(12, 12)`